# Mysql Precedence Logic

Tags: mysql, operators, logic

Any explanation to the following queries :

```
Select x FROM y WHERE a = 1 OR a = 2  AND (b = 1 OR b = 2)
```

why it doesn't return the correct info while this return the correct info :

```
Select x FROM y WHERE (a = 1 OR a = 2) AND (b = 1 OR b = 2)
```

Am i missing something here ?

```
      X   Y   (X OR Y)  X OR Y   


      1   0     1         1 
      0   1     1         1
      1   1     1         1
      0   0     0         0
```

I know in term of precedence the () have priority , but why should i add them the the first part of the query ?

Correct me if I'm wrong

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AND` has a higher precedence than `OR` so your first query is equivalent to this:

```
Select x FROM y WHERE a = 1 OR a = 3 OR (a = 2  AND (b = 1 OR b = 2))
```

Which is not equivalent to

```
Select x FROM y WHERE (a = 1 OR a = 2 OR a = 3) AND (b = 1 OR b = 2)
```

I guess you forgot the `a = 3` part in your first query.

[Operator precedence in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operator-precedence.html)

Answer (score 1):

Because ambiguity is an undesirable trait?

Also, the optimizer will re-order your WHERE Conditions if it thinks it will perform better. Your ambiguity will, therefore, cause different results depending on how/what it evaluates first.

Always be explicit with your intentions.

Answer (score 1):

Using parentheses in your WHERE clause does not just affect precedence but also groups predicates together. In your example the difference in results is more a matter of grouping rather than precedence.

You could think of this: (pN = predicate expression)

```
WHERE a = 1 OR a = 2  AND (b = 1 OR b = 2)
```

as:

```
WHERE p1 OR p2 AND p3
```

And this:

```
WHERE (a = 1 OR a = 2 OR a = 3) AND (b = 1 OR b = 2)
```

as:

```
WHERE p1 AND p2
```

and so it becomes clear that the results could be quite different.